# Creating certificate and encrypting pdf (using certificate) using iTextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I need to protect a PDF using certificate.

I need to create a certificate (that Adobe reader and acrobat understands, .pfx file) on a local machine of a user. The certificate is created using the email id of the user.

Then I need to generate the same certificate on my machine and use this certificate to encrypt a PDF giving few rights to the user like no printing, no copying etc.

The basic idea is that when I'll send this PDF to the user, and the user tries to open it, Acrobat/Reader will look for the certificate and if certificate is present on the local machine of user, Acrobat/Reader opens the PDF with the rights applied on the PDF (ie no printing, no copying etc).

I need to develop an application in C# using iText5 for .NET to achieve the above. I am new to C#.

Is this workflow possible to protect PDF?
I am unable to find any sample to generate self signed certificate using iText5 for .NET.

Also, how can I use self signed certificate to encrypt a PDF file using iText5 for .NET?

Comment: Hi, I have a similar requirement, I know it has been a while since this question, but how have you solved it? I would really appreciate if you can give me some information.

Answer (score 0):

Try [iSafePdf](http://isafepdf.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I want to do it programmatically. Can someone please give me some sample or link to sample.

Comment: mentioned "iSafePDF" is an open source project based on the iTextSharp project: http://isafepdf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets